# Existe um tipo de moderador universal da Stack Overflow?

Tags: debate

Existe alguém que gerencia **todos** os sites da Stack Overflow? Um tipo de administrador? Tal que pode transferir reputação,  contas, etc?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Existem gerentes de comunidade, como o [Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe), que têm mais poderes que os moderadores e, como funcionários da SO Inc., têm acesso a quem tem ainda mais poderes. Mas nem tudo é permitido. Por exemplo, eles podem mesclar duas contas do mesmo site, mas não podem transferir reputação entre contas (ninguém pode, são regras que eles próprios definiram).

No site da empresa tem a [lista de todos os funcionários](http://stackexchange.com/about/team).

Comment: Também não podemos marcar uma resposta como aceita `:D`

Comment: Ou desbloquear usuários!

Comment: @Gabe Seu "losango" deveria ser um retangulo entao :p

Comment: O link de funcionários tá quebrado e não aponta mais para algum lugar...

Answer (score 21):

Sim, custa só 7 dólares. Recomendado!

[image]

Comment: :D hahahahahaha

Comment: @rray, ups, acho que não entendi a pergunta, você tinha que fazer -1 :D

Comment: A piada foi boa, não tinha como xD

Comment: Sem nenhum desrespeito ao seu discipulo CypherPotato, a deixa era muito boa, tou rindo até agora do "moderador universal", lol

Comment: Se fizer um desenho ou editar a imagem pode virar um meme hahaha

Comment: Já antevejo a próxima meta-pergunta: `Usuário com "muita" reputação trollando o Meta`. Tá faltando drama e lágrimas neste Meta!! O que me traz ainda a uma outra pergunta: `Quanto de drama é necessário pra um Meta saudável?`

Comment: @brasofilo Tentar descobrir isso é justamente o meu trabalho `;)`