# Quem vigia os vigilantes?

Tags: debate

Se por algum motivo um Moderador não gostar de mim porque ofendi ele de forma pessoal e irreversível, e isso resultar em uma vingança pessoal com muitos down votes,  outro Moderador poderá intervir? Existe algum tipo de "presidente"? Existe democracia no SOpt?

Comment: acho que moderador não se preocupa em ficar negativando coisas, conheço dois inclusive que dedicam seu tempo apenas a cuidar das flags e postagens com problemas graves que afetem a comunidade. Você deve estar confundindo Moderadores com "usuários avançados".

Comment: Pq você ofenderia um usuário (moderador) do site de forma pessoal? xD ficou estranho isso.

Comment: Eu tava escrevendo isso @rray :p

Comment: O fato de um usuário fazer um ataque pessoal a outro não fornece de forma alguma argumento ou direito para retaliação. O que pode ser feito é reportar (seja para moderação ou via contato do site) essa atitude e não revidar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento punição de 24hs está longe de ser o máximo que pode ser feito :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vale para todos que fizeram algo abusivo. No caso de moderador vai pegar bem mal :)

Comment: @bigown concordo, só queria dizer que se o AP ofendeu um moderador, teria que ser uma "ofensa" tipo um xingamento (muitos usuários confundem qualquer critica, comentário ou desentendimento com uma ofensa) e duvido muito que um moderador "com poderes" iria se preocupar em negativar, sendo que ele tem acesso a punir o usuário com uma suspensão. Resumindo o que quero dizer é que o medo dele me parece que ele confundiu moderador com "usuário avançado".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tens razão mas é sempre bom clarificar que mesmo moderadores estão sujeitos as regras do site como os outros.

Comment: Poxa pessoal, não tem haver com medo ou se é usuário avançado ou moderador, ou se eu ofendi ou não, tem haver com o fato do poder ser restrito ou irrestrito. Interessante saber que existe "punição".

Comment: Ainda sim resumindo, se vc @MarcusBecker, teve um comportamento ofensivo, o que vai gerar é um punição para ti e não downvotes para ti. Se você apenas teve um desentendimento e ainda sim o moderador esta tendo um comportamento equivocado use a flag, existe mais de um moderador, existe a Staff. O processo como funciona eu desconheço.

Comment: Bela questão levantada pelo rapaz do post.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Moderadores

Em geral é difícil um moderador fazer isso, eles foram eleitos moderadores porque não costumam ter esse tipo de comportamento. Mas se ocorrer, outros moderadores podem fazer alguma coisa. Pra falar a verdade costuma ocorrer o contrário e moderadores sofrem vinganças por alguma ação de moderação que desagradou o usuário :) Ainda que aqui no SOpt isso é mais raro também. Existe vez ou outra usuários negativando usuários, independente de ter alguma posição extra.

Se acontecer, pode postar algo no meta para discutir. A própria comunidade já pode ajudar. Se deseja um contato privado, é possível também, mas o moderador sempre saberá do que está ocorrendo, mesmo que não saiba o texto específico da denúncia.

Em geral moderadores não saem fazendo o que bem entendem e o que afeta mais fortemente um usuário é discutido entre os moderadores ativos.

## Moderação comunitária

Lembrando que de certa forma todos somos moderadores no site. Estou entendendo que está falando dos que possuem "diamante" e foram eleitos, portanto possuem alguns privilégios extras para executar sua tarefa.

## Community Managers

E ainda existem os [Community Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team), funcionários da empresa dona do site, que [podem fazer em um nível acima se forem contatados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Muito raro precisar em toda rede, mas está lá se achar que precisa. Esse conteúdo não será visto pelos moderadores.

E claro que existem superiores a eles se fizeram algo irregular. Em última instância há o presidente da empresa. Que na verdade deve responder para um conselho. E responde perante legislação. Ninguém é livre para fazer o que quer :)

## Democracia

Existe uma certa democracia. Nem é para ter 100% porque <strike>democracia é uma filosofia muito boa e funciona melhor que outras formas em sociedades abertas</strike> (ainda acho isto, mas é como socialismo, funciona bem no papel, nunca vimos funcionar de fato), mas em comunidades mais restritas é preciso ter um pouco mais de controle. Mas de forma geral é bem democrático. Temos até [eleições para moderação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elei%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Existem deslizes aqui ou ali, coisa normal.

Answer (score 22):

É bom recordar que os moderadores são utilizadores do site que foram escolhidos pela comunidade para voluntariamente desempenhar tais funções no seu tempo livre e por empenhamento ao site e comunidade.

Acima de nós (moderadores e membros da comunidade) há funcionários da SE que monitorizam o site, um deles é o Gabe, nosso CM (*Comunity Manager*).

Para além disso as ferramentas de moderação que dispomos deixam um histórico que nós moderadores podemos ver. Ou seja, se um moderador usar as ferramentas ou outros podem ver esse histórico.

Em relação a votos sabemos que são secretos mas o próprio site tem mecanismos para detectar abusos de votos (nos dois sentidos) e pode reverter os mesmos.

Em todo o caso, moderador ou não, havendo abuso ou necessidade de sinalizar um comportamento pode usar-se as ferramentas de sinalização disponível aos membros da comunidade ou enviar e-mail para a equipa do site.

Comment: E se todos os moderadores estiverem combinados com o moderador acusado?

Comment: @JorgeB, em casos onde haja essa suspeita o melhor seria [contactar a equipa da SE](http://stackoverflow.com/company/team).

Comment: @jorgeb Nesse caso melhor fechar logo o site :P

Comment: @bfavaretto Ou o usuário em específico fez algo tão grave que chateou todos os moderadores :p

Comment: @Randrade não seria o primeiro caso, e mesmo assim não deu em votos de vingança :) Pessoalmente acho o conjunto que faz a equipa de moderadores aqui bem razoável. Mas vamos ver que o que o futuro traz :P

Comment: @bfavaretto pelos vistos já aconteceu noutro site, mas eu perguntei mais por saber que alguém mais tarde irá ter essa dúvida e também para ficar a saber se for preciso responder no PL ;)

Comment: @Sergio acho que aqui não estão em causa os moderadores do site, mas sim uma pergunta mais genérica. :)

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, e é bom levantar-se a questão para refletir sobre possiveis cenários :)

Answer (score 21):

Basicamente, quando um moderador está envolvido, dependendo do caso, quem arbitra o caso será um outro moderador, [eis um exemplo recente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5675/132) (e diga-se de passagem, na minha opinião, o moderador envolvido agiu de forma correta). Os moderadores do SOpt são (em ordem alfabética) o [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto), o [bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown), o [Math](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/math), o [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray), o [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) e o [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz).

Dependendo da complexidade do caso, ele pode ser escalado para os "*Community Managers*" (CM) que são funcionários assalariados da Stack Exchange que tem a finalidade de gerenciar e cuidar das comunidades, inclusive dos moderadores. Aqui no SOpt temos o [Gabe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) com essa função. Se por algum motivo, o Gabe estiver envolvido ou não puder lidar com a situação e os moderadores regulares também não, talvez o [JNat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23291/jnat), que também é CM e também fala português, possa resolver. Se a situação extrapolar tudo isso, aí vai ter que ser escalado aos CMs gringos. A lista completa e atualizada dos "*Community Managers*" pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/176034).

No último dos últimos casos, quando todos os moderadores estiverem envolvidos ou não puderem atuar e uma boa parte dos CMs estiverem na mesma situação, a situação pode chegar até a diretoria do Stack Exchange, onde há o [Jaydles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347414/jaydles) e o [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky). Deve haver outros na diretoria da SE, mas não sei ao certo.

Quanto mais, casos onde a coisa foge totalmente do controle e acabam saindo das mãos dos moderadores são bastante raros, e a maior parte deles ocorrem nos bastidores sem o conhecimento do público em geral.

O único caso que sei aqui no SOpt que virou uma batata quente nas mãos dos CMs foi o da proposta do SUpt, mas esse teve uma participação mínima dos então moderadores, e escalou por outros motivos.

Em outros sites da rede, só conheço quatro casos graves (e bem graves) envolvendo moderadores: dois deles no site de [ficção científica e fantasia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), onde no primeiro, um moderador foi destituído e no segundo, um moderador renunciou e abandonou o site e um outro ex-moderador também apagou a sua conta; Um outro no site de [engenharia elétrica](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) em que um moderador renunciou e suspendeu a si mesmo; e no [puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), onde ocorreu um escândalo em que todos os moderadores estavam envolvidos, vários CMs acabaram por ter que se envolver também e o caso chegou na diretoria da SE. O bigown também citou um quinto caso de um moderador da comunidade de [engenharia de software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) que desistiu e sua conta hoje está deletada. Espero nunca ter casos cabeludos e complicados como esses por aqui.

Quanto a democracia, eu diria que o SOpt é significativamente democrático. Entretanto, não se engane achando que é uma democracia absoluta, pois não é. Em 99% das vezes, tudo ocorre de forma democrática. Mas nesse 1%, se a Stack Exchange decidir por tomar alguma decisão de forma unilateral, eles vão tomar, estejam eles corretos ou não. Eles podem e vão ouvir a comunidade, mas não vão se submeter ou concordar com ela sempre.

Comment: Já me estou a rir com "virou uma batata quente nas mãos dos CMs foi o da proposta do SUpt" ahahahah

Comment: Fiquei muito curioso por saber o que se passou nesses casos todos :P

Comment: @JorgeB. Não quero colocar links para esses pepinos aqui. :)

Comment: Me manda por e-mail! (piada)

Comment: @MarcusBecker Não convém ficar falando muito sobre essas coisas. A ideia não é fazer uma inquisição ou levantar um dossiê. Eu só coloquei isso para dizer que casos assim já ocorreram antes, mas que são muito raros.

Comment: Foi só brincadeira, não a curiosidade, mas a parte do e-mail.

Comment: Na verdade o SUpt, até onde imagino, escalou, mas não foi um caso de abuso de ninguém. Tem coisas que cabe decisão colegiada mesmo. Bom conhecer esses casos. Eu sei de outros, de dar rolo, de moderador que "se suicidou" na rede.

Comment: @bigown De fato. Editado. Quanto a esse "suicídio", fiquei curioso, mas não vou insistir para que você fale. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa note que foi entre aspas :) Foi no SE.SE (ex Programmers), era o único moderador lá que eu acho que era coerente, mesmo qdo eu discordava dele. Talvez o maior erro é ter desistido. Eu entendo que tem caso para se afastar porque pode não atender seus objetivos, mas eu acho que a pessoa se afastar porque as coisas não são do jeito que quer seja é meio autoritário.

Answer (score 18):

Votos em série, sejam positivos ou negativos, são revertidos - basta esperar um tempinho para que isso ocorra.

Caso veja algum tipo de abuso por um moderador, você pode comunicar usando a opção [entre em contato conosco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) no rodapé do site, os CMs responsáveis lidarão com esse problema.

**Relacionado:**

[Existe um tipo de moderador universal da Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4475/91)

Comment: Mas a questão são os votos pontuais. Aquele voto que são 'dois em um dia', 'dois em outro dia', e por ai vai. Infelizmente, acho que nessa comunidade ocorre isso. Acredito que seja  algo difícil de controlar.